# Spring 4 , REST Service returns a 415 error from Tomcat

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, tomcat

I am trying to test the POST method in a REST service with Spring 4. It works fine in my integration tests with `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup` but I deployed it in a Tomcat 8.5.8 and I can no understand why it is not working. I receive this message:

```
                              HTTP Status 415 -

   type Status report

   message

   description The server refused this request because the request entity
   is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the
   requested method.
     ________________
```

but the Tomcat Server receives this request (extracted from wireshark):

```
POST /app-1.0-SNAPSHOT/v1.0/concentrators/ HTTP/1.1 
User-Agent: curl/7.35.0 
Host: x.x.x.x:8080 
Accept: */* 
Content-Type: application/json 
Content-Length: 528 {"street":"street","num":"num","code":"code","town":"town"
,"descriptionRoom":"descriptionRoom","btPwd":"btPwd"
,"gprsPwd":"gprsPwd","gprsLogin":"gprsLogin","gprsApn":"gprsApn"
,"gprsPin":"gprsPin","motherboardId":"motherboardId","logLevel":0
,"frameSendPeriod":0,"frameCapturePeriod":0,"mQTTServerPwd":"mQTTServerPwd"
,"mQTTServerUser":"mQTTServerUser","mQTTServerIp":"mQTTServerIp"
,"ftpServerPwd":"ftpServerPwd","ftpServerUser":"ftpServerUser"
, "ftpServerIp":"ftpServerIp","numSerie" :"numSerie","idConcentrator":-1,"infoCameras":[]}
```

It seems fine I don't know where is the mistake.

My REST service is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "application/json" }, produces = { "application/json" })
public ResponseEntity<String> post(@RequestBody ConfigurationConcentrator configurationConcentrator) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    try {
        configureConcentrator.create(configurationConcentrator);
    } catch (IncorrectDBOperation | ErrorSendMessageException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(e.getMessage(), headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Also, It checked the jackson dependencies (databind, core and annotations) and they are added in .war file.
This is my curl command:

```
 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data  @addConcentrator2.json http://x.x.x.x:8080/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT/v1.0/concentrators/
```

It seems, It can not resolve correctly which interceptor needs, but I don't see the problem:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = { "application/json" }, produces = { "application/json" })
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<ConfigurationConcentrator> get(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
....
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "application/json" }, produces = { "application/json" })
    public ResponseEntity<String> post(@RequestBody ConfigurationConcentrator configurationConcentrator) {
....

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = { "application/json" }, produces = { "application/json" })
    public ResponseEntity<String> put(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody ConfigurationConcentrator configurationConcentrator) {
....

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/cameras/{idcamera}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = { "application/json" }, produces = { "application/json" })
    public ResponseEntity<String> putCameras(@PathVariable("id") String id, @PathVariable("idcamera") String idCamera,
....

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/cameras", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "application/json" }, produces = { "application/json" })
    public ResponseEntity<String> postCameras(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody List<ConfigurationCamera> configurationCameras) {
....
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/initialconfiguration", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = { "application/json" }, produces = { "application/json" })
    public ResponseEntity<StatusInitialConfiguration> getInitialConfiguration(@PathVariable("id") String numSerie) {
....


    }
```

**UPDATE1:**
I updated the curl command with the Accept header.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" --data  @addConcentrator2.json http://x.x.x.x:8080/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT/v1.0/concentrators/
```

**UPDATE2:**
I think, It is detecting two interceptors:

```
06:36:41.011 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapping [/v1.0/concentrators/1/camera
s] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [gasnatural.ConcentratorController@74e5ead6] and 2 interceptors
06:36:41.011 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from han
dler [gasnatural.ConcentratorController@74e5ead6]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported
06:36:41.011 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [gas
natural.ConcentratorController@74e5ead6]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported
06:36:41.011 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [gasnat
ural.ConcentratorController@74e5ead6]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported
06:36:41.011 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatc
her': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
06:36:41.011 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

**UPDATE3:**

Classes to map JSON:

Configuration concentrator

```
package gasnatural.models;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ConfigurationConcentrator {
    public static class InfoCamera {
        public Long idCamera;
        public String numSerie;
    }

    private String street = null;
    private String num = null;
    private String code = null;
    private String town = null;

    private String descriptionRoom = null;

    private String btPwd = null;
    private String gprsPwd = null;
    private String gprsLogin = null;
    private String gprsApn = null;
    private String gprsPin = null;
    private String motherboardId = null;
    private int logLevel = -1;
    private int frameSendPeriod = -1;
    private int frameCapturePeriod = -1;
    private String mQTTServerPwd = null;
    private String mQTTServerUser = null;
    private String mQTTServerIp = null;
    private String ftpServerPwd = null;
    private String ftpServerUser = null;
    private String ftpServerIp = null;
    private String numSerie = null;

    private Long idConcentrator;
    private List<InfoCamera> infoCameras;

    public ConfigurationConcentrator() {

    }

    public ConfigurationConcentrator(String street, String num, String town, String code, String descriptionRoom, String btPwd, String gprsPwd,
            String gprsLogin, String gprsApn, String gprsPin, String motherboardId, int logLevel, int frameSendPeriod, int frameCapturePeriod,
            String mQTTServerPwd, String mQTTServerUser, String mQTTServerIp, String ftpServerPwd, String ftpServerUser, String ftpServerIp, String numSerie) {

        this(new Long(-1), street, num, town, code, descriptionRoom, btPwd, gprsPwd, gprsLogin, gprsApn, gprsPin, motherboardId, logLevel, frameSendPeriod,
                frameCapturePeriod, mQTTServerPwd, mQTTServerUser, mQTTServerIp, ftpServerPwd, ftpServerUser, ftpServerIp, numSerie,
                new ArrayList<InfoCamera>());
    }

    public ConfigurationConcentrator(Long idConcentrator, String street, String num, String town, String code, String descriptionRoom, String btPwd,
            String gprsPwd, String gprsLogin, String gprsApn, String gprsPin, String motherboardId, int logLevel, int frameSendPeriod, int frameCapturePeriod,
            String mQTTServerPwd, String mQTTServerUser, String mQTTServerIp, String ftpServerPwd, String ftpServerUser, String ftpServerIp, String numSerie,
            List<InfoCamera> infoCameras) {

        this.descriptionRoom = descriptionRoom;
        this.btPwd = btPwd;
        this.gprsPwd = gprsPwd;
        this.gprsLogin = gprsLogin;
        this.gprsApn = gprsApn;
        this.gprsPin = gprsPin;
        this.motherboardId = motherboardId;
        this.logLevel = logLevel;
        this.frameSendPeriod = frameSendPeriod;
        this.frameCapturePeriod = frameCapturePeriod;
        this.mQTTServerPwd = mQTTServerPwd;
        this.mQTTServerUser = mQTTServerUser;
        this.mQTTServerIp = mQTTServerIp;
        this.ftpServerPwd = ftpServerPwd;
        this.ftpServerUser = ftpServerUser;
        this.ftpServerIp = ftpServerIp;
        this.numSerie = numSerie;

        this.street = street;
        this.num = num;
        this.code = code;
        this.town = town;

        this.descriptionRoom = descriptionRoom;
        this.infoCameras = infoCameras;
        this.idConcentrator = idConcentrator;
    }

    public void addIdCamera(InfoCamera idCamera) {
        this.infoCameras.add(idCamera);
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public String getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public String getTown() {
        return town;
    }

    public String getDescriptionRoom() {
        return descriptionRoom;
    }

    public String getBtPwd() {
        return btPwd;
    }

    public String getGprsPwd() {
        return gprsPwd;
    }

    public String getGprsLogin() {
        return gprsLogin;
    }

    public String getGprsApn() {
        return gprsApn;
    }

    public String getGprsPin() {
        return gprsPin;
    }

    public String getMotherboardId() {
        return motherboardId;
    }

    public int getLogLevel() {
        return logLevel;
    }

    public int getFrameSendPeriod() {
        return frameSendPeriod;
    }

    public int getFrameCapturePeriod() {
        return frameCapturePeriod;
    }

    public String getmQTTServerPwd() {
        return mQTTServerPwd;
    }

    public String getmQTTServerUser() {
        return mQTTServerUser;
    }

    public String getmQTTServerIp() {
        return mQTTServerIp;
    }

    public String getFtpServerPwd() {
        return ftpServerPwd;
    }

    public String getFtpServerUser() {
        return ftpServerUser;
    }

    public String getFtpServerIp() {
        return ftpServerIp;
    }

    public String getNumSerie() {
        return numSerie;
    }

    public Long getIdConcentrator() {
        return idConcentrator;
    }

    public List<InfoCamera> getInfoCameras() {
        return infoCameras;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public void setNum(String num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public void setTown(String town) {
        this.town = town;
    }

    public void setDescriptionRoom(String descriptionRoom) {
        this.descriptionRoom = descriptionRoom;
    }

    public void setBtPwd(String btPwd) {
        this.btPwd = btPwd;
    }

    public void setGprsPwd(String gprsPwd) {
        this.gprsPwd = gprsPwd;
    }

    public void setGprsLogin(String gprsLogin) {
        this.gprsLogin = gprsLogin;
    }

    public void setGprsApn(String gprsApn) {
        this.gprsApn = gprsApn;
    }

    public void setGprsPin(String gprsPin) {
        this.gprsPin = gprsPin;
    }

    public void setMotherboardId(String motherboardId) {
        this.motherboardId = motherboardId;
    }

    public void setLogLevel(int logLevel) {
        this.logLevel = logLevel;
    }

    public void setFrameSendPeriod(int frameSendPeriod) {
        this.frameSendPeriod = frameSendPeriod;
    }

    public void setFrameCapturePeriod(int frameCapturePeriod) {
        this.frameCapturePeriod = frameCapturePeriod;
    }

    public void setmQTTServerPwd(String mQTTServerPwd) {
        this.mQTTServerPwd = mQTTServerPwd;
    }

    public void setmQTTServerUser(String mQTTServerUser) {
        this.mQTTServerUser = mQTTServerUser;
    }

    public void setmQTTServerIp(String mQTTServerIp) {
        this.mQTTServerIp = mQTTServerIp;
    }

    public void setFtpServerPwd(String ftpServerPwd) {
        this.ftpServerPwd = ftpServerPwd;
    }

    public void setFtpServerUser(String ftpServerUser) {
        this.ftpServerUser = ftpServerUser;
    }

    public void setFtpServerIp(String ftpServerIp) {
        this.ftpServerIp = ftpServerIp;
    }

    public void setNumSerie(String numSerie) {
        this.numSerie = numSerie;
    }

    public void setIdConcentrator(Long idConcentrator) {
        this.idConcentrator = idConcentrator;
    }

    public void setInfoCameras(List<InfoCamera> infoCameras) {
        this.infoCameras = infoCameras;
    }

}
```

Configuration camera

```
package gasnatural.models;

public class ConfigurationCamera {
    private String numSerie = null;
    private String numCamera = null;
    private String cups = null;

    private String status = null;

    public ConfigurationCamera() {

    }

    public ConfigurationCamera(String numSerie, String numCamera, String cups, String status) {
        this.numSerie = numSerie;
        this.numCamera = numCamera;
        this.cups = cups;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getNumSerie() {
        return numSerie;
    }

    public String getNumCamera() {
        return numCamera;
    }

    public String getCups() {
        return cups;
    }

    public void setNumSerie(String numSerie) {
        this.numSerie = numSerie;
    }

    public void setNumCamera(String numCamera) {
        this.numCamera = numCamera;
    }

    public void setCups(String cups) {
        this.cups = cups;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE4**

I simplified the mapped object class , and I receive the same error.

```
public class DTOConfigurationConcentrator {
    private String street;
    private String num;

    public DTOConfigurationConcentrator() {
        super();
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(String num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

}
```

It seems something related to the tool for the json serialization but I don't know exactly how I can check this.

Comment: in your request headers , change Accept: */* to  Accept: application/json

Comment: I added the header in the curl command which I use to test, I receive the same error...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444855/spring-rest-post-json-requestbody-content-type-not-supported Can you check if you have similar problem?

Comment: Can you post the `ConfigurationCamera` class? The json may be malformed or the class can not be deserialized.

Comment: I uploaded the classes which I am mapping. It seems the deserialization problem, but I don't know how It passed my integration tests. Also, I don't which variable gives problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to tag my configuration class with `@EnableWebMvc`...