# spring boot mvc - Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In [this spring boot project](https://github.com/MaxHoefl/springboot-jpademo) I get an error when `POST`ing (using Postman) a new `Item` resource

```
Resolving exception from handler 
     [public com.example.demo.resource.Item com.example.demo.controller.ItemController.addItem(com.example.demo.resource.Item)]: 
     org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: 
     Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

In the request body I copied one of the existing `Item`s that I got from a `GET` request (and changed the `id` and `itemName`)

```
    // Request body:
    {
        "id": 10, // also tried without id field as it's autogenerated
        "itemName": "milk",
        "cart": {
            "id": 1
        }
    }
```

I made sure that I have the correct getters and setters in the `Item` class (as this is a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444855/spring-rest-post-json-requestbody-content-type-not-supported))

```
@Entity
@Table(name="items")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@JsonIdentityInfo(
          generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
          property = "id")
public class Item
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "item_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="item_name")
    private String itemName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id", nullable=false)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Cart cart;

   //setters and getters
}
```

Here is also the `Cart` class to which `Item` has a `many-to-one` relationship

```
@Entity
@Table(name="carts")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
          generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
          property = "id")
public class Cart 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "cart_id")
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Item> items;

    //setters and getters
}
```

This is the `ItemController`

```
@RestController
public class ItemController 
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ItemController.class);

    @Autowired ItemDao dao;

    @GetMapping("items")
    public List<Item> getAll()
    {
        List<Item> res = new ArrayList<>();
        dao.findAll().forEach(res::add);
        return res;
    }

    @PostMapping("items")
    public Item addItem(@RequestBody Item item)
    {
        return dao.save(item);
    }

    @GetMapping("items/{item_id}")
    public Item getItemById(@PathVariable("item_id") long item_id)
    {
        Item item = dao.findById(item_id).get();
        LOG.info(" ---------------- Retrieved item: {}", item.toString());
        return item;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I just noticed that there seems to be another error preceding:

```
Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.example.demo.resource.Item]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.Set) not compatible with managed type (com.example.demo.resource.Item)
```

Here is the full error:

```
2018-02-27 11:03:09.836  WARN 9640 --- [nio-9200-exec-1] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.example.demo.resource.Item]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.Set) not compatible with managed type (com.example.demo.resource.Item)
2018-02-27 11:03:09.837  WARN 9640 --- [nio-9200-exec-1] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.example.demo.resource.Item]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.Set) not compatible with managed type (com.example.demo.resource.Item)
2018-02-27 11:03:09.838 DEBUG 9640 --- [nio-9200-exec-1] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Failed to resolve argument 0 of type 'com.example.demo.resource.Item'

org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please share controller code aswell

Comment: @Rakesh please see the `ItemController` above (appended)

Comment: when you are posting data, set contenttype=application/json, ignore charset and try.

Comment: yes all I have set in Postman is `Content-Type=application/json`

Comment: Try changing type of `id` from `long` to `Long` and also the setters/getters for id in both `Item` and `Cart` class

Comment: @theLearner tried that but problem persists

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not use `Collection, Map, Array or enumeration` as `@JsonBackReference` .

Refer the link : https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html.

Try interchanging `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference`. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue.
//@JsonBackReference dosen't matter.
Delete  //@JsonManagedReference, it works.

Many:

```
@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Device.class, mappedBy="detectUnit") 
private List<Device> devices;
```

One:

```
@ManyToOne
private DetectUnit detectUnit;
```

POST method works for both.

Comment: Yes, removing just the `@JsonManagedReference` will just work although the Jackson Javadoc states that `@JsonBackReference` should not be used on a collection. Anyway, I would suggest creating DTO classes for different use cases of CRUD of the entities in order to avoid serialization and deserialization issues.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing Content type from `'application/json;charset=UTF-8'` to `'application/json'`. I had the same issue and that fixed mine.