# One to many and one to one relationship using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have `Order` class and `OrderDetails` as shown below. Now I have `one to many` relationship between order and orderdetails and `one to one` in other direction.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "createdAt" }, allowGetters = true)
public class Order implements Serializable {

    @JsonView(View.V1.class)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long orderNo;

    //@NotBlank
    //private String orderNo;

    @JsonView(View.V1.class)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;

    //@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    //@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    //@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    //@JoinColumn(name="id")
    @JsonView(View.V1.class)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="order")
    private Set<OrderDetails> orderDetails;

    @JsonView(View.V1.class)
    @Email(message="Email should be valid")
    private String email;
}
```

As can be seen `Order` has atrr. `set of orderDetails`. And `OrderDetails` has an attr. `Order`. Due to this  when I am saving Order object, I am getting Order object which has OrderDdrtails attr. which has again Order attr. which has OrderDetail and so on as shown below:

```
[{"orderNo":1,"createdAt":"2019-04-16T16:26:02.000+0000","orderDetails":[{"id":1,"itemId":1,"quantityOrdered":50,"order":{"orderNo":1,"createdAt":"2019-04-16T16:26:02.000+0000","orderDetails":
```

One thing I can do is set `order` inside `orderDetails` as `null`. But is there any other approach I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate `Order` in your `OrderDetails` with `@JsonIgnore` (or in `Order` if you wish). This way only children will be shown in json after marshalling.

Or better use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` to handle relationships. More about it [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion). Basically you would have to annotate set of `OrderDetails` with `@JsonManagedReference` and `Order` with  `@JsonBackReference`.

Comment: so it is that during serialization the data is getting populated in nested manner and it has nothing to do with hibernate. Pls correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: In some way it has, hibernate is responsible for creating a bidirectional relationship. But it can be handled by jackson only.

Comment: Your solution worked but with a small change. Pls have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49008167/6407858. So need to change the order of `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference` as mentioned in the answer.