# MockMvc with SpringBootTest is throwing exception HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException when testing the controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

I am testing request validation in Spring RestController with the help of integration testing and MockMvc.

**ControllerTest.java**

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Controller.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
class ControllerTest {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    private Service service;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Test
    void createOrAdd_shouldReturnErrorResponseOnInvalidInput() throws Exception {
        Request request = Request.builder()
                .name("name<script>")
                .primaryEmail("test@mail.com")
                .build();

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/create")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request))
                .characterEncoding("utf-8"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isBadRequest());
    }
}
```

**Controller.java :**

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class Controller {

    private final Service service;

    public Controller(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/api/create", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<GenericResponse<Response>> createOrAdd(@RequestBody @Valid Request request, Errors errors) {
        GenericResponse<Response> genericResponse = new GenericResponse<>();
        try {
            if (errors.hasErrors()) {
                throw new RequestParamsException(errors.getAllErrors());
            }
            Response response = service.createOrAdd(request);
            genericResponse.setData(response);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(genericResponse);
        } catch (RequestParamsException ex) {
            genericResponse.setErrors(ex.getErrors());
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(genericResponse);
        }
    }
```

**Error** :

```
WARN 17304 --- [           main] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=utf-8' not supported]

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /api/create
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=utf-8", Accept:"application/json", Content-Length:"162"]
             Body = {"name":"name<script>alert(1)</script>","primary_email_address":"test@mail.com"}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.org.controller.Controller
           Method = com.org.controller.Controller#createOrAdd(Request, Errors)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 415
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Accept:"application/octet-stream, text/plain, application/xml, text/xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/*+xml, multipart/form-data, multipart/mixed, */*"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<400> but was:<415>
Expected :400
Actual   :415
```

I have used the correct `Content-Type` and `Accept` Headers while making a call in `Test.java` using `mockMvc`, but still it's giving HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException. Tried many combinations in `Accept` and `Content-Type` but still not working.

I have read many SO questions related to this exception, but couldn't find what's the issue here.
Still not able to figure out why it's saying HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.

**Update** : After removing `addFilters = false` as suggested, not able to find the handler itself.

```
    MockHttpServletRequest:
          HTTP Method = POST
          Request URI = /api/create
           Parameters = {}
              Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=utf-8", Accept:"application/json", Content-Length:"162"]
                 Body = {"name":"name<script>alert(1)</script>","primary_email_address":"test@mail.com"}
    Session Attrs = {org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN=org.springframework.security.web.csrf.DefaultCsrfToken@7a687d8d}   

     
Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null
    
    Resolved Exception:
             Type = null
    
    ModelAndView:
            View name = null
                 View = null
                Model = null
    
    FlashMap:
           Attributes = null
    
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 403
    Error message = Forbidden
          Headers = [X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

    
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<400> but was:<403>
Expected :400
Actual   :403
```

**Request** :

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class CreateAgencyRequest {

    @NotNull(message = "name can't be null")
    @JsonProperty(value = "name")
    @Pattern(regexp = REGEX_CONST, message = "name is not valid")
    private String name;

    @NotNull(message = "primary_email_address can't be null")
    @JsonProperty(value = "primary_email_address")
    private String primaryEmail;

}
```

Comment: Does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444855/spring-rest-post-json-requestbody-content-type-not-supported) help you? If not, can you share `Request` class definition?

Comment: @ShivajiPote, added the request.

Comment: Use `@WebMvcTest` instead of `@SpringBootTest` (makes your test considerably faster) remove the `@ExtendWith` (doesn't add anything here).  The `characterEncoding` isn't needed so I would suggest to remove it, as that influences the content type (see the request). The 403 you use indicates you have security setup and failed to add the CSRF token to the request (that is clearly in the error!), you need to add it to the request (or disable security as proposed in the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take a look at your test.

```java
@WebMvcTest(classes = Controller.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
class ControllerTest {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    private Service service;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void createOrAdd_shouldReturnErrorResponseOnInvalidInput() throws Exception {
        Request request = Request.builder()
                .name("name<script>")
                .primaryEmail("test@mail.com")
                .build();

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/create")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request))
                .characterEncoding("utf-8"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isBadRequest());
    }
}
```

First the `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` doesn't add anything as you are using, correctly, the `@MockBean` annotation which is handled by Spring. So you should remove that.

Next the `@SpringBootTest` is for bootstrapping the **full application** to run an integration test. What you want is a sliced test for the web, so instead of `@SpringBootTest` use `@WebMvcTest` this will make your test considerably faster. You can then also remove `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` as that is added by default.

You disabled all filters with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)` probably due to the 403 you got. The 403 you have is the result of enabling CSRF (enabled by default) and not adding that to the request. If you don't want CSRF (you probably want it) either disable that in the Security configuration, or if you want it modify your request.

Looking at the error you have the culprit is the `characterEncoding` being added to the content type, so you probably want/should remove that.

With all that your test should look something like this.

```java
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.*;

@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)
class ControllerTest {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @MockBean
    private Service service;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void createOrAdd_shouldReturnErrorResponseOnInvalidInput() throws Exception {
        Request request = Request.builder()
                .name("name<script>")
                .primaryEmail("test@mail.com")
                .build();

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/create")
                        .with(csrf()) // Add CSRF field for security
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isBadRequest());
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** If you also have authentication in place you might also need to add a user/password to the request as [explained here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/mockmvc/authentication.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Deinum. As mentioned in other comment certain issues still persists  By using only annotation```@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)``` on the test class,  it's giving the exception as ```Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...).```. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Though I tried using ```@ContextConfiguration(classes = Controller.class)``` with ```@WebMvcTest(controllers = Controller.class, excludeAutoConfiguration = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)```, and unexpectedly it worked somehow. Even though same controller class is mentioned in ```@WebMvcTest``` as well.
```@WebMvcTest(controllers = Controller.class, excludeAutoConfiguration = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Controller.class)
``` this is what I am using currently to make it work, but again, why do we need ```@ContextConfig```

Comment: It doesn't work it is a hack/workaround. Did you structure your packages differently and don't have a proper `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class? As that should, ideally and recommended, be in the top-level package.

Comment: So basically, I have currently multi-module maven project. In which there's```@SpringBootApplication``` in a module name ```app```. And then in another module I have ```Controller.java``` and ```ControllerTest.java``` named ```module1```. But I even tried to move ```ControllerTest.java``` class in ```app``` module still same exception.

Comment: Do we have to mention the ```@ContextConfiguration(classes = Controller.class)``` in the application to make it work if they exists in different packages. And only controller class is sufficient or it's dependency also need to be added.

Comment: You shouldn't need it and the fact that you do shows some error in either your configuration or structure of your application.

Comment: Re-quoting ```But I even tried to move ControllerTest.java class in app module still same exception```. When I do this, test fails and shows error like many config dependency beans are not present to autowire, even though for ```controller``` only ```Service``` is the dependency.

Comment: Ehrm... app module?! Also do you have additional annotations on your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated test? If so that might be part of your issue.

Comment: Yes I have like 
```PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
@EnableTransactionManagement, 
@EnableScheduling, 
@EnableRetry, 
@EnableAsync```

Comment: You don't need that. Spring boot already loads `application.properties` this only interferes with that, transaction management is already enabled. Move the others to a dedicated configuration class. If you don't Spring Boot has no way to exclude them while loading the configuration for `@WebMvcTest` and you will get errors about non existing beans...

Comment: Got it. Have few other .prop files to load config from not just ```application.properties``` like ```@PropertySource("classpath:common.properties")```, can we mention them in one seperate config file and have them injected in any Bean globally via ```@Value``` or available by var = ```Environment```.

Comment: You can use `spring.config.additional-locations` to specify additional files, but why those files in the first place instead of putting everything in `application.properties`. (Although that is another question).

Comment: Just wanted to separate properties related to different s/w components like ```DB/Cache/Queue/some common prop``` at different .prop files for better readability and code understanding.

Comment: Which goes against the flexibility of Spring Boot and the loading of properties as you now have hardcoded that for all environments and no possibility to override. However as stated that is another question :)>

Answer (score 0):

How about adding `consumes` and `produces` in your controller endpoint? Apparently, endpoint does not accept the content type you send in request:

```java
mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/create")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

You tell endpoint "hey, I am sending JSON and I only accept JSON response back". But endpoint says "Look, among what I accept, there is no JSON, so please rethink!"

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 415
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Accept:"application/octet-stream, text/plain, application/xml, text/xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/*+xml, multipart/form-data, multipart/mixed, */*"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

So adjust accordingly.

```java
@RequestMapping(
    produces = {"application/json"}, 
    consumes = {"application/json"}, 
    method = RequestMethod.POST
)
```

All other configs, testing, injections are irrelevant. Good to have, but does not solve your problem.

Answer (score -2):

I think you are missing @WebMvcTest(controllers = Controller.class)

Comment: Tried using that as well, ```@WebMvcTest(controllers = Controller.class```, still error as forbidden 403.

Comment: `@SpringBootTest` will also work but a lot slower then `@WebMvcTest`. They serve different purposes.